# Redirect to external URI, even if it's not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**General info:**

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 application that sends emails and tracks link-clicking from within each email. When some user follows a link, they performs a GET query to my web server with certain query parameters. Meanwhile, my application saves information about the click and redirects user to the initial (target) site.

**Closer to the point:**

The links in mails may be arbitrary (e.g. *http://www.google.com*, *//google.com*, *www.google.com*) or even not valid (e.g. *ab//cd*). My application doesn't care about the string values of urls (even if it's like *\asdf//sadg:*) and will simply paste them directly to the address bar.

For this purpose I tried to use `Redirect` and `RedirectPermanent` methods, and the `UriBuilder` class. `Redirect` and `RedirectPermanent` may combine addresses and try to redirect to the local path if the url is specified without a scheme. `UriBuilder` manages to add a scheme if needed, but it throws exceptions when the url is invalid. JavaScript `location.replace` has the same behavior as c# `Redirect`, by the way.

**The issue:**

How can I redirect to arbitrary urls from my ASP.NET MVC controller without any validations and redirects to local paths?

Comment: Just to verify: you do understand that redirect requires valid url, while address bar actually performs essentially search over several possible options to find valid url... So you need to decide which one you planning to implement and actually need help with.

Comment: Btw I can't imagine why do you want to do this...

Comment: @DannyChen, have you ever used MailChimp service? In this case, my application is to work very similar. Users can compose letters on their own in html format and paste ordinary links (e.g. '<a href="//abc">abc</a>'). While sending, the app substites primary urls with smth like _http://example.com/?target=//abc_. At best, users wouldn't even notice the intervention of my application. Consequently, I shouldn't change the links or redirect to local error page, even if they are invalid.

Comment: @Alexei, certainly. I am looking for a way to paste urls directly in the address bar. For instance, when I type _http://aaaa/aa_ my browser says "This site can't be reached". My app is to work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the Redirect() method and just pass in a string.  I don't think it tries to validate the given URI as long as you pass it in as a string.

Tested and "works" (Browser receives the correct location header):

```
return Redirect("\asdf//sadg:");
```

If you want to do this "manually", you could do something like this to perform the redirect by yourself:

```
    Response.AddHeader("Location","whateverurl");           
    HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Moved;
    return new ContentResult() { Content = String.Empty };
```

Comment: You misunderstood, it shouldn't redirect to a local page and append some header. I've described the situation more extensively for @DannyChen. I've also tested 'return Redirect(@"\asdf//sadg:")', and it opens local page like _example.com/asdf/sadg:_.